# Get First Option Text on Button Click Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-plugins

I am having a select field in which I am trying to achieve something like when the dropdown is selected, datatable will be sorted accordingly. Once the user is done with sorting, There is a button to clear all values of dropdown and get the general value to show all rows without sorting. The values are taken fine except the text of the value remains the same.

```
//dropdown
<select value='Deliver To' name="_location" id="_location" class="SlectBox form-control">
    <?php echo location(); ?>
</select>

//PHP to get results to dropdown
function location(){
    global $con;
    $output.= '<option value="_allCity">All Results</option>';
    $_selectquery= "SELECT * FROM _tableone";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $_selectquery);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $output.= '<option value = "'.$row["name"].'">'.$row["name"].'</option>';
    }
    return $output;
}

//Button to reset dropdown
$('#reset').click(function(){
    $('#_location').val('_allCity').change();
    $('#_location').text('All Results').change();
});
```

When I reset the value is taken correctly but the text is still the manually selected one.

Comment: please elaborate more on your issue .

Comment: Hi Swati. Simply, A select dropdown in which the data are fetched from SQL as how it is mentioned above. When I select the options from the dropdown, There is a datatable below. that will be sort and filtered as per dropdown's value. after, There is a button to reset the table. Once its clicked, All result has to be shown without any sorting with the value of 'All Results' which is the first option of dropdown.

Comment: then what do you mean by `text is still the manually selected one..` ? as you said value is taken then it should shown first option only . Are there more option with same `value` ?

Comment: if I reset, the value of the dropdown changes, but not the selected text. i.e. : 
first option : value = _all : text > All Item
selected option : value = _selected : text > Selected Item Text

press reset
selected option : value = _all : text> Selected Item Text - This doesn't change.

Comment: try like this : `$("select#_location").val($("select#_location option:first").val());`

Comment: Nope Swati, Unfortunately it didn't work. nothing happened on the button click.

Comment: It is working just fine you can check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qt3jgh7z/) . Maybe problem is somewhere else.

Comment: okay, the problem is there are four dropdowns are being used for filtering purposes. four of dropdowns have SlectBox class. everything works fine if that particular class is removed.

Comment: can you edit your question with more codes which shows that behaviour  ?

Comment: @Swati can I get you on chat?